# Yii2 does not find action

Tags: php, yii2

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
         '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
         '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Not it is clear why references of a **/controller/name-action/id/1** do work, **/controller/1/name-action** do not work, and without hyphen everything works, according to documentation of action **name-action** it is **actionNameAction**??

```
public function actionNameAction($id) {
    // some code
}
```

[Inline Actions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#inline-actions)

In advance all thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` does not include `-`.

Change pattern to `[\w\-]+`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with zend framework and Yii2.In yii2 it is actionActionName.While using it in url's the capitals are changed to lower case with a hyphen preceding them.
For example,
if the controller is Orders
and the action is OrderAnalysis
then the url would be something like orders/order-analysis.
Moreover any id or any other parameter is added only after routing the app to its correct controller action.
Also now coming to your problem I think i found a backdoor to it-

> // creates an anchored URL:  /index.php?r=post%2Fview&id=100#content --------------------------
>             echo Url::to(['post/view', 'id' => 100, '#' => 'content']);